# Aligning checkbox to the right in list view item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-checkbox

[image]

Its hard to see the checkbox, but I cant seem to put the box on the right side of the list item.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="#FF00B8FF"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingBottom="14dp"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the checkbox to be on the right side of the list item. 
Im not sure where i'm doing it incorrectly. I have tried several combinations of layout_gravity and weight. 
Thanks!

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`. Ofcourse, you can achieve what you need, with `LinearLayout`, but there will be too much cascading of `LinearLayout` tags which is not recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this!

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left|center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="#FF00B8FF"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingBottom="14dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/linear"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/linear"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

:)

Comment: Thank you. Android list view layouts are worse then root canal work.

Answer (score 1):

i don't quite get what you want to achieve, but i presume you want to achieve the image you provided above.

Have you tried to wrap both of your Linear layout with a horizontal layout like below?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title Line 1, EXAMPLE"
            android:textColor="#FF00B8FF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="SubTitle Line 1, EXAMPLE" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="right">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want the checkbox to be on the far right. along the right wall

Comment: The trick is to set the width to fill the remaining spaces (in this case "fill_parent") and set the gravity of the Linear layout to right, this will anchor the content of the linear layout to right (in this case, the checkbox). I've tried it and it does the trick.